# How can I remove the space between a character in HTML? Padding doesn't work

Tags: html, css, fonts, padding

[image]

Why is there space(marked in red color) before the letter 'അ', even if I added padding as 0px?

```
<span style="margin:0;padding:0;border:1px solid blue;font-size:128px">അ</span>
```

Comment: Please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/8HYuC/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That space is part of the font. Use a negative <s>`letter-spacing`</s> `margin-left` on it in order to remove it.

**[Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2437505)**

**Note:** this only moves the entire span a few px back. In reality, the space is still there and cannot be properly removed.

Comment: But it depends on the font. Better make sure you're not getting overlap when using another font.

Comment: You only healed the symptom, but not the cause.

Comment: @hakre: As the old saying goes: That's not a bug, it's a feature!

Answer (score 4):

In typography, spacing between characters is often adjusted due to esthetic and readability considerations. The spaces are there even in common ascii letters:

```
<span style="margin:0;padding:0;border:1px solid blue;font-size:128px;letter-spacing:0px;">a</span>
```

[image]

But the space is different because of different variables like what is the previous and next character.

You can achive some results by playing with negative `padding` and `letter-spacing`

[More info](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/letter-spacing.html)

Comment: `letter-spacing` doesn't remove the space, instead, it's more like a margin on each letter.

Comment: Yes, I know, but can only apply the margin to the span, not to individual letter inside a span. It's tricky. The article linked goes deep on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

White spaces occur from working with inline positioning and spans are always inline elements. Solution here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Have you looked at lettering.js? Its a jquery plug-in that works specifically for typography.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...