# Minimize extra space within glyph

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove the extra space within an icon so that there is no space around the edge of the actual glyph.

Here is an example of a character that does not have this problem. The letter extends to the edge of the available space:

```css
span::after {
  content: "a";
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

And here is an example of a character that has this problem:

```css
span::after {
  content: "▾";
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

How can I make the second example look like the first?

Comment: Have a looksie at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259888/how-can-i-remove-the-space-between-a-character-in-html-padding-doesnt-work)

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Good find, but it seems like that solution can only work for one side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```css
span{
 background-color: red;
 font-size: 30px;
 letter-spacing: -5px;
}
strong
{
    margin-left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <strong>
           ▾
  </strong>
</span>
```